# Python print string centered

Tags: python, string, printform

I would to print centered a string that is more than 1 line

```
a = "*\n*\n**"
```

I tried with

```
print '{0:^20}'.format(a, 'centered')
```

but it put in the center just the first *, how can i put all the string in center?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does center the entire string:

```
>>> '{0:^20}'.format(a, 'centered')
'       *\n*\n**       '
```

Note that this puts seven spaces before and after `a`.  I think you are expecting it to center the content of each line, here is how you can do that:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{0:^20}'.format(x, 'centered') for x in a.split('\n'))
         *
         *
         **
```

Comment: `>>> '{0:^20}'.format(a, 'centered')` returns the repr output, so it does center   only the first `*`.

Comment: There's also: `'\n'.join(x.center(20) for x in a.splitlines())`